# Replacing the token in spring config xml using maven profile

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc

I have spring configuration file which can not be changed much. I want to have configuration value define in maven `pom.xml` file using the `<profile>`

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="${img.base.path}" />
```

I want to replace the `${img.base.path}` with the value defined in `pom.xml` file as

```
<profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <properties>
            ....
            <img.base.path>D:/engagementjunction/images/</img.base.path>
        </properties>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <url>http://10.18.1.48:8080/manager/text</url>
                        <server>tomcat_dev</server>
                        <path>/ej</path>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/webapp/spring</directory>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.xml</include>
                    </includes>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

When I am running `mvn package -P dev -DskipTests`. It does not replace the token `${img.base.path}` in spring xml config file.

Comment: Ok, so what have you tried?

Comment: Can you shared your pom with us?

Comment: Edited the code with profile.

Answer (score 1):

As Gabriel already pointed out, resources configuration may not be part of profile (see http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html#Which_areas_of_a_POM_can_be_customized_by_each_type_of_profile_Why)

What you can do is split your definitions. Put the resource definition in your main POM, but the properties in your profiles:

```
<properties>
    ....
    <!-- if you REMOVE the default value, it will not be replaced -->
    <img.base.path>DEFAULT_VALUE</img.base.path>
</properties>

<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/webapp/spring</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>

<profile>
    <id>dev</id>
    <properties>
        ....
        <img.base.path>D:/engagementjunction/images/</img.base.path>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring expects those properties from .properties files. Maven does the filtering on these property files.

So your resource filter should be like this:

```
<resource>
   <directory>location/to/properties/file</directory>
   <filtering>true</filtering>
   <includes>
        <include>**/*.properties</include>
   </includes>
</resource>
```

Also, your resource filtering configuration should not be profile-specific. It needs to be in the *project>build>resources* path

Comment: No I can't go with this approach. I have tried. Configuration are scattered in application. And changing is big task. So, I decided to replace this token using the mvn profile.

Answer (score 0):

This is as an alternative in case you can modify the application context to this extent:

If you can add the [SimpleCommandLinePropertySource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/SimpleCommandLinePropertySource.html) to your Environment, it will read properties from your command line and override any other property:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     CommandLinePropertySource clps = new SimpleCommandLinePropertySource();
     AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
     ctx.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addFirst(clps);
     ctx.register(AppConfig.class);
     ctx.refresh();
 }
```

Comment: It's good alternative. But can't be fit into my requirement. I am not allowed to change the configuration. Again the token must be replaced in spring config file using the mvn profile. :)